# How can I encrypt the returned Json from an WebAPI controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

i want to develop a WebAPI controller inside my asp.net MVC3 that send password when it is envoked, it looks similar to:

```
public string GetPasswordByUserId(int id)
{
    var password = user.password.FirstOrDefault((u) => u.Id == id);
    if (password == null)
    {
         throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    return password;
}
```

But how can i encrypt the returned password?

second question: and if the above action method is inside an APIController, then does this means that the returned string will be serialized as Json format by default?

Answer (score 2):

For password encryption you can use symmetric key with RC2 which uses `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace/ assembly.

```
byte[] toEncryptPwd = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToEncrypt);
RC2 encPwd = RC2.Create("RC2");

strToEncrypt = Convert.ToBase64String(encPwd.CreateEncryptor(Key, rgbIV).TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptPwd, 0, toEncryptPwd.Length)); // strToEncrypt is now encrypted
encPwd.Clear();
```

// You have to hardcode the key and rgbIV somewhere in the code or in database.

Why you want to return password as json? I did not follow the design and need.

> Return type will be json or not?

The web-API supports auto content negotiation which means if the client which is requesting the API using HTTP, puts accept header as `Accept: application/json` then json reponse is sent else if the client puts `Accept: application/xml` in header then the API returns xml response.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it needs to be decrypted on the client side?  Then use HTTPS/SSL.

A string is not automatically serialized, or at least serialized to the object you want.  Return the type you want serialized and Web API will automatically serialize it.